# Multiple Clicks inside li element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following structure :

```
<li onclick='GetMyTopic({1});' class='SideBarBoxli SideBarBoxLiSelected' id='MyTopics{0}'>

<div style='float:right; padding-top:3px;'><a href='{0}'> <span>{1}</span></a></div>

<div > <a  id='img{2}'  onclick='DeleteTopic({0},{1})' href='#'> <img  src='../../../images/delete.png' height='16' width='16'/></a></div>

</li>
```

When I click the img Delete of the first span, the li click is also invoked.

I just want when I click delete img the delete img script only gets invoked and not the li. Same for the span element.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, add a `return false`, e.g.:

```
DeleteTopic({0},{1}); return false;
```

This will stop the `click` event from [bubbling up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to the `<li>` element, triggering its handler as well.

Comment: This will only stop page PostBack. The li is still clicked though